# angular2 populate table data for specific row

Tags: angular

In one div I am populating only few columns of a table, and when I click on 'See' for a specific row, I want to see remaining columns of that table(right now it populates all the rows, but natural).

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
            <div class="populate-table" [hidden]="!halls">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Landmarks</th>
                        <th>Seating capacity</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of halls">
                        <td> {{ item.name }} </td>
                        <td> {{ item.landmarks }} </td>
                        <td> {{ item.seating_capacity }} </td>
                        <td> <a (click)="clicked(item.id)"> See </a> </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
            <div [hidden]="!openDiv">
                <p>Remaining details of the selected hall will appear here</p>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of halls">
                        <td> {{ item.ac }} </td>
                        <td> {{ item.avg_user_rating }} </td>
                        <td> {{ item.rent }} </td>
                    </tr>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

My component function:

```
halls: Object;
    openDiv : boolean;
    specific_hall : Object

    constructor(private homeService: HomeService){}

    fetchData(cityId: any) {

        if(this.openDiv==true){
            this.openDiv=false
        }

        this.homeService.fetchData(cityId).then(
            data => {
                this.halls = data;

            });
    }

    clicked(item: any){

        this.openDiv=true;
        this.specific_hall=this.halls[item]

    }
```

What I have to do fix this? The second table could also be a list for better viewing purpose.

Comment: can you give some more detail? what is the exact problem?

Comment: I would recommend changing the `click` event to `clicked(item)`.  Then in the `clicked()` set a property such as `selectedItem` to that item.  Then use `selected item to populate your second table.

Comment: @Dave can you perhaps explain a bit with code how do mean it? I am updating my code with component function.

Comment: Look at what @micronyks posted as an answer...that's exactly what I was talking about

Comment: @Nitish see my answer, I also included a demo plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should do, `(click)` should set a `specific_hall` and then when that property is set show the next table with more details based off of the `specific_hall`

### [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/v8ZjAJaDoHaB8KLxlNjx?p=preview)

make your `html` look like this

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
        <div class="populate-table" [hidden]="!halls">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Landmarks</th>
                    <th>Seating capacity</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of halls">
                    <td> {{ item.name }} </td>
                    <td> {{ item.landmarks }} </td>
                    <td> {{ item.seating_capacity }} </td>
                    <td> <a (click)="clicked(item)"> See </a> </td> <!-- MAKE CHANGE HERE -->
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"> <!-- THIS WHOLE DIV CHANGED -->
        <div *ngIf="specific_hall">
            <p>Remaining details of the selected hall will appear here</p>
            <ul>
                <li>AC: {{ specific_hall.ac }}</li>
                <li>Avg User Rating: {{ specific_hall.avg_user_rating }}</li>
                <li>Rent: {{ specific_hall.rent }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Make your component look like this

```
halls: Object;
specific_hall : Object

constructor(private homeService: HomeService){}

fetchData(cityId: any) {

    if(this.specific_hall){
        this.specific_hall = null;
    }

    this.homeService.fetchData(cityId).then(
        data => {
            this.halls = data;

        });
}

clicked(item: any){

    this.specific_hall = item // <-- CHANGE THIS

}
```

Comment: @Nitish Sure! Glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do **`ngFor`** again for the selected item.

```
<td> <a (click)="clicked(item)"> See </a> </td> ///<<<===changed

clicked(item){
   ...
   this.selectedItem=item;                       ///<<<===added. assign selected object to selectedItem
}
```

---

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
            <div [hidden]="!openDiv">
                <p>Remaining details of the selected hall will appear here</p>
                <tr>
                        <td> {{ selectedItem.ac }} </td>  
                        <td> {{ selectedItem.avg_user_rating }} </td>
                        <td> {{ selectedItem.rent }} </td>
                    </tr>
            </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: When I do it, I get `Cannot read property 'ac' of undefined` error, why?